# user interface for microsoft.aspnetcore.identity

Tags: user-interface, authentication, identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using .Net Core 2.0, and selected "Individual User Accounts" on my site creation. I can register/login/logout, and I see tables in my database for claims, logins, roles, and users.

I then installed the Microsoft.AspnetCore.Identity nuget package, which didn't seem to add anything to what I already have.

I'm hoping there's a user interface component to these packages. Basically do I need to build all of my UI management crud operations or can I get that off the shelf somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft hasn't built an admin UI for Identity even though they had done so for ASP.NET membership with [WSAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Web_Site_Administration_Tool).

Thinktecture [IdentityManager](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager) was a replacement for Identity 2.0 and Skorunka František [adapted it](https://github.com/skorunka/IdentityManager/) for Identity 3.0 (Core).

So typically each user has rolled their own solution including [Identity Manager](https://github.com/mguinness/IdentityManager) as an example for ASP.NET Identity Core.